# Сколько хранятся фиддлы

Tags: jsfiddle

Вопрос странный но кто знает. Сколько по времени хранятся фиддлы зарегистрированных пользователей, а сколько незарегистрированных.

Comment: Судя по очень старому посту http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171371/how-long-does-jsfiddle-host-your-code-for , они должны храниться вечно. В комментариях были жалобы на удаленные фиддлы, но при выборочной проверке они все оказались доступны.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку